# query_vars Filter: Would You Ever Use It When $_GET is Available and You Don't Need a 'Pretty' URL?

Tags: query-string, query-variable

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the uses cases/best practice for the 'query_vars' filter, and query_vars in general, when I could use the $_GET global instead.

Given http://example.com/my-page/?mykey=myvalue:

- If I'm not altering the query, I understand that it wouldn't be appropriate to add 'mykey' as a query var.
- But if I AM going to alter the query using the 'pre_get_posts' hook, I can still grab 'mykey' from the $_GET global and use it without issue, provided I don't care about pretty permalinks and am not rewriting the URL. Is there some reason I shouldn't be using $_GET in this case?

Comment: Did you even find a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @KimberlyW - No, not really.  It appears like using query_vars is just 'the right way' to do things whenever you're passing something that alters the main query.  Otto has a good explanation of the concept of query_vars here [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16373) .